# What is the difference between git pull origin [another_branch] vs git rebase [another_branch]?

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-pull

I know git pull creates a new commit and rebase goes commit by commit and make it on top of another. Other than the extra merge commit is there any other difference or danger involved?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+difference+pull+rebase

Answer (score 0):

`git pull` fetches the commits from the remote repository, then merges the commits into the current branch. As a result, a merge commit will be created.
A merge commit is not created for a fast-forward merge.

`git rebase` moves commits from one branch on top of commits from another branch. The commit history looks more transparent. No extra commits.

Also you can use `git pull --rebase`. As a result, after the data is fetched, a rebase will be performed instead of a merge.

Comment: I know that but my question is "Is there any difference in the end result?"